# Load widget only on blog posts

Tags: posts, widgets

I am attempting to ensure a widget is only loaded on blog post pages.

I tried using `$post_type = get_post_type( $post_id );` inside the widget function of my widget class. However, upon loading pages like the homepage, 'archives', 'categories' etc. . . the post type is always 'post'. The only exception is when I create a page, it returns 'page' as expected.

Is there a way to actually ensure the current page is a post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [is_single()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single):

```
if ( is_single() ) {
    // Do widget, which will only appear on single-post templates
}
```

Comment: This will still allow it to load on 'page' post types. However, this solved the problem I was having. I can implement another filter with get_post_type() in addition to using is_single() if I really need to limit to just posts. Thank you!

Comment: Makes sense, you could do something like if (is_single() && !is_page()) { do_widget(); }